# Ember - wait for everything to be loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-select

I have in my App many different Select Views that load data from a restful app via Ember-data;
i need to execute some code only when everything is done: all the select view have finished loading and rendered...

Is there a callback i can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Promises [Link](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#sts=A%20Word%20on%20Promises...)

```
// Note: jQuery AJAX methods return promises
```

var usernamesPromise = Ember.$.getJSON('/usernames.json');

usernamesPromise.then(fetchPhotosOfUsers)
                .then(applyInstagramFilters)
                .then(uploadTrendyPhotoAlbum)
                .then(displaySuccessMessage, handleErrors);